# Clojure opposite of reduce?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I run into this problem a lot (more often in clojurescript) but haven't noticed how others deal with it. This is what I want:

```
[:div.container [:div.first "first"] [:div.second "second"] [:div.third "third"]]
```

And let's say I'm building it from a collection like: `["first" "second" "third"]`

I'll pass the collection through a `mapv` and wind up with (this code is a sketch, I'm not using it):

```
(mapv
  #([(keyword (str "div." %)) %])
  ["first" "second" "third"])
=> [[:div.first "first"] [:div.second "second"] [:div.third "third"]]
```

And if I were to use it inside the container div, I'd get:

```
[:div.container [[:div.first "first"] [:div.second "second"] [:div.third "third"]]]
```

I've been using things like `cons` to put the `:div.container` at the front of the result of `mapv`. But in my mind there should be a better way--like an opposite of `reduce`. Is there such a thing?

**Edit:** I did find `concat` and it looks like I've tried it before, but I get a sequence back. I want a vector. `(vec (concat ... ))` is not ideal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the idiomatic way to prepend to a vector in Clojure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095714/what-is-the-idiomatic-way-to-prepend-to-a-vector-in-clojure)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
 (apply vector :div.container 
               (mapv #(vector (keyword (str "div." %)) %) 
                     ["first", "second", "third"]))
```

The idea is to use `apply` to pass each element of the result of `mapv` as an individual argument to `vector`.

As a bonus, `apply` admits other arguments before the collection argument, so we can stow the `:div.container` there.

(Here using `mapv` vs. `map` would be indifferent.)

(Also, the "opposite" of `reduce` is usually called [`unfold`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr) in other languages, but I havent found the analogous function in the core Clojure libraries.)

Comment: there is an `iterate` fn (http://conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.7.0-alpha4/clj/clojure.core/iterate/) in clojure which looks exactly like `unfoldr` for me

Comment: @Dima `unfold` is a bit more general, because it can generate finite sequences, and has an "internal state" whose "type" can be different from the type of the results. Here are two Clojure implementations: http://www.enrico-franchi.org/2011/08/clojure-unfold-and-anamorphisms.html http://www.matlux.net/blog/2014/05/04/anamorphic-adventure-in-clojure

Answer (score 1):

`cons` is fine here -- it's been around since the dawn of Lisp and it's useful for exactly what you want to do here.

Here's how I'd approach this:

```
(defn containerize
  [tag v]
  (let [kw #(keyword (str tag "." %))]
    (into [] 
      (cons (kw "container")
        (map (fn [x] [(kw x) x]) v)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

The "opposite of reduce" is reduce.

```
(reduce (fn [v s]
          (conj v [(keyword (str "div." s)) s]))
        [:div.container]
        ["first" "second" "third"])
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that [:ul ([:li "one"] [:li "two"])] will work as expected?

I think if you change (mapv f coll) to

```
(map f coll)
```

or

```
(doall (map f coll))
```

You'll get the result you're looking for.